# Access VBA Back Color Gradient For Label/Shape

Tags: ms-access, vba, gradient

I'm looking for a way in Access VBA to set the backcolor of a label, shaped, etc as a gradient. I'm currently applying solid colors but was hoping there is a way to accomplish this via a gradient.

Here is how I'm currently applying a back color in Access:

```
    Label2.BackColor = RGB(119, 49, 65)
```

Here was the code I was using in Excel, to fill a cell as a gradient, worked well. However, I'm not sure exactly how Access VBA would work. Suggestions to point me in the right direction?

```
    Range("D14").Select
    With Selection.Interior
    .Pattern = xlPatternLinearGradient
    .Gradient.Degree = 0
    .Gradient.ColorStops.Clear
    End With
    With Selection.Interior.Gradient.ColorStops.Add(0)
    .Color = 2786997
    .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    With Selection.Interior.Gradient.ColorStops.Add(1)
    .Color = 1447704
    .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
```

Answer (score 1):

A Label cannot have a gradient background.

[image]

If you want to set the gradient on a button you can do that [similar to before](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195423%28v=office.15%29.aspx).

```
button.Gradient = 12
```

Comment: What a bummer. Well I sorta have a workaround, I created an image, with the gradient I needed, turned the Visible to "NO" and turn on the image when needed via VBA. I guess its the long way around for this. Thanks for your suggestion though!

Comment: A button can be used as a label just as well and it responds to changes in your theme (if that happens) and can be resized easily. You just need to make sure the hover/pressed colors are the same as the normal fore/back colors so it doesn't change it's look when someone interacts with it (because a label does not). Both an have text and both have click events (a button just has a lot of other events)

Comment: There's no way to change the colors of the gradient is there? Looks like only one color gradient.

Comment: I _think_ you're right. If you want two colors you will need to do your way. As far as I can tell you get to pick a color and access will darken or lighten it. :/